# padding is padding around the content but this is not fully correct

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new to CSS. According to the documentation is padding around the contents.
In this example is the content "Gifts and Special Offers"
In this simple example I set padding-right to 150px which should mean according to docs that I should have 150px of space to the right of the contents. But I dont have 150px of empty space to the right of the contents. I must have missed something here convering the understanding ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Chapter 5: Indestructible Boxes</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    h3
    {
        margin:50px;
        padding:0px 150px 0px 0px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:200px; background:red;">
    <h3>Gifts and Special Offers</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

//tony

Answer (score 3):

[Padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) is the inner spacing.

[Margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) is the outer spacing.

When you give `h3` the following styles, you actually wraps it with `50px` of outer spacing from all directions, and extra `150px` inner spacing to the right.

```
margin: 50px;
padding: 0px 150px 0px 0px;
```

That makes horizontal spacing of `50px + 150px + 50px = 250px`.

[image: Resulted spacing]

Notice that your div is only `200px` wide, so you're gonna have troubles with getting what you're expecting.